# css and html not connecting

Tags: html, css

Hey I´m a newbie in this field. My little css project is just showing ( I think ) only html part of the code.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #262626;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}
.container
{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 70px auto 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: wrap;
}
.container .box
{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: ff0;
    margin: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;

}
.container .box .imgbox
{
    position: relative;
}

.container .box .imgbox img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: transform 2s;
}
.container .box:hover .imgbox img
{
    transform: scale (1.2);

}
.container .box .details
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background: rgab(0,0,0,.8);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transition: transform .5s;
}
.container .box:hover .details
{
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
.container .box .details .content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
.container .box .details .content h2
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ff0;

}
.container .box .details .content p
{
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="C:\Users\Timur\Desktop\Samo button\style.css" rel="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>
    <title>button</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="imgbox">
                <img src="img/obraz1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <h1> liek </h1>
               <p> liek </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `rel="style.css"` should be `rel="stylesheet"`

Answer (score 4):

I guess "not connecting" means you can't see how your css looks like, right?
I think this occurs because of your link line.

The href attribute must be a reachable path&file from your webbrowser (if you are running that in your localhost it may work, but wont work when you upload it to a server)

The rel attribute doesn't expects a relative path, it wants to know what type of file are you linking. So, if you didn't use the "type" attribute it will use the "rel" to know what it is.

You may try this to find out if it works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

and store the style.css file in the same directory where you have that html file. Once you see if works, you can experiment to move it somewhere else